# Force Browser to render closest font color descendant.

Tags: html, css, descendant

```
<style>.f-1, .f-1 a {
    color: #fff;
}
.f-2, .f-2 a {
    color: #000;
}</style>

<body class="f-2">
     <ul class="f-1">
        <li><a>TEST COLOR</a></li>
     </ul>
</body>
```

Because f-2 in the css follows f-1 the browser renders the TEST COLOR white (#fff).  How can I make it so its renders whatever is the closest descendant?

Answer (score 0):

I second Vivek's suggestion. Both the rules `.f-2 a` and `.f-1 a` have the same [**specificity**](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade#Specificity). So you have to make the rule you want to be applicable on `TEST COLOR` more specific. You can try `.f-1 > a` or `.f-2 .f-1 a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inherit` feature. This can inherit parents property.

```css
span {
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.extra span {
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is blue, as span elements are set to be.
</div>

<div class="extra" style="color:green">
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is green, because it inherits from its parent.
</div>

<div style="color:red">
Here is <span>a span element</span> which is blue, as span elements are set to be.
</div>
```